# Is there an easy way to edit a json file with python

Tags: python, regex, json, updating

There are some similar questions to this lying around but I couldn't find anything that does what I'm looking for.

The code I'm using is as follows (python 2.75): (EDIT, updated to include suggestions for clarity:

```
def write_json(entry):
  current_players = []
  with open("Dota2data.txt","r+") as outfile:
     data = json.load(outfile)
     for member in entry.players:
        current_players.append(member['account_id'])
     data["matches"].append({"match":entry.match_id, "winner":entry.radiant_win, "players":current_players})
     json.dump(data, outfile)
     outfile.close()
  pass
```

I'm basically trying to add a new match instance within the 'matches' key each time this function is running (it is called when a new match is loaded).

However, as I'm sure you've noticed this will just replace the text file with the most recent result each time.

I know that I can use appending to add a new match to each line, but because I'm stubborn I want to add the data within the 'matches' field. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Edit: I just want to add, tonight is my first time playing around with this and I'm pretty new to python too.

That answer was a great help, I've now got some momentum to finish this. Thanks for your help! For reference: final code is as follows.

```
def write_json(entry):
   current_players = []
   with open("Dota2data.txt","r+") as infile:
      data = json.load(infile)
      for member in entry.players:
         current_players.append(member['account_id'])
      data["matches"].append({"match":entry.match_id, "winner":entry.radiant_win, "players":current_players})
      infile.close()
   with open("Dota2data.txt","r+") as outfile:
      json.dump(data, outfile)
      outfile.close()
   pass
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue with writing to the file? Can you be more specific why you object to rewriting the file? Is the file getting larger quickly? What are you planning to use this file for?

Comment: write_json is called whenever I am evaluating a new match. The issue is that my Dota2data.txt file only contains one line. As I go through the matches it just writes over the previous entry with the newer entry.

I am basically trying to build a json database for use in another program later. Right now I'm just trying to get some functionality that I can build on.

Comment: unrelated: don't call `.close()` inside `with`-statement for the file. `with`-statement closes the file for you both on success and on error, that is its purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: before of anything , load the file.

```
with open("Dota2data.txt","r+") as outfile:
```

Sure, first lets load the json file into an object.

```
data = json.load(outfile)
```

Then, add a new property inside `'matches'` as a dictionary.

```
data['matches'].append({'match':entry.match_id, 'winner':entry.radiant_win, 'players':current_players})
```

Finally, output the file.

```
json.dump(data, outfile)
```

**FULL CODE**:

```
def write_json(entry):
    with open("Dota2data.txt","r") as infile:
        for member in entry.players:
            current_players = current_players.append(member['account_id'])
        data = json.load(infile)
        infile.close
        data['matches'].append({'match':entry.match_id, 'winner':entry.radiant_win, 'players':current_players})
        with open("Dota2data.txt","w") as outfile:
            json.dump(data, outfile)
            outfile.close()
```

Comment: Hey, I'm likely just sleepy but I can't get this to work :/.

I get a syntax error from 

    data['matches'][]

So I've removed the second [] (I'm not too familiar with dictionaries). I then get this error:

ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: EDIT: Oops, I hadn't defined the matches key within my data file.. Having done that, I'm getting the following error: IOError: [Errno 0] Error.

It looks to me like 2 different file descriptors are used for reading and writing though?

edit2: Only just saw your response, I am still getting the same error with this change. Thanks for your help by the way, I should have said that far sooner!

Comment: You need to open the file as `r+` instead of `w`.

Comment: What would you recommend to fix the error? (I'm still not entirely sure as to why it's occuring). EDIT: It is being opened as r+ now, I changed that after your first fix

Comment: Thanks, the full code cleared my misunderstanding up. In case any one else uses this as a reference I'll place my final code at the end of my answer (it is slightly different to yours only in terms of the output of the program)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Change your quotes to "" instead of '' for json.loads. Or, you can use ast.literal_eval() instead.

EDIT2: Let me clarify, JSON uses double quotes for syntax, while python can use either. If you're calling json.loads, use double quotes for your JSON. If you want to use single quotes, use `ast.literal_eval`. Make sure you `import ast`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I've changed to double quotes now.

Answer (score 0):

```
def update_file(path, entry):
    with open(path) as infile:
        data = json.load(infile)

    current_players = [member['account_id'] for member in entry.players]
    data["matches"].append({
        "match": entry.match_id,
        "winner": entry.radiant_win, 
        "players": current_players
    })

    with open(path, "w") as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile)
```